# Entity Framework Insert multiple foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
Patient.DivHospitalID (FK)
DivHospital.HospitalID (FK)
Hospital.HospitalID (PK)
```

I need to insert into DivHospital the Hospital and link/insert into Patient the DivHospital.

```
Patient tp = new Patient();
DivHospital dh = new DivHospital();

dh.HospitalReference.EntityKey =
     new EntityKey("transportPagerEntities.Hospital", "hospitalID", hospital);
         tp.DivHospitalReference.EntityKey = new  
         EntityKey("transportPagerEntities.DivHospital", "divHospitalID", hospitalref);

context.AddToDivHospital(dh);
context.AddToTransportPatient(tp);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't dealing with PKs (ints) and since you are using an ORM you shouldn't be.

You don't need to do the EntityKey stuff, just set them directly.

```
Patient tp = new Patient();
DivHospital dh = new DivHospital();

dh.Hospital = hospital;
tp.DivHospital = hospitalref;

context.AddToDivHospital(dh);
context.AddToTransportPatient(tp);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am dealing with PKs.

Patient.DivHospitalID (FK) => DivHospital.DivHospitalID (PK)
DivHospital.HospitalID (FK) => Hospital.HospitalID (PK)

I need to create the DivHospital "record" and then link that with Patient.

Answer (score 1):

With EntityFramework this is really easy (if I understand your problem):

```
Patient tp = new Patient();
DivHospital dh = new DivHospital();

dh.Patient.Add(tp);  //magic

context.AddToDivHospital(dh);
context.SaveChanges();
```